# How to set more than one tag in views object using id?

Tags: android, android-view

As shown in picture, it says there might be memory leak. I'm trying to tag holder and another object in `convertView`. What am I suppose to do? Could I ignore that?

[image]

Comment: This could be a very bad ViewHolder pattern design. You are trying to use setTag(int key, Object tag) method. However, inside that you are setting the 'key' value as R.id.holder and R.id.tagged_object which are CONSTANTS!.                                                                                            The key values for the setTag method should use something unique for every row. You could use the position variable of the `getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` as the key instead.

Comment: "incident" object is also unique. Because that's just an object of the adapter arraylist of current position.

Comment: Incident incident = (Incident) getItem(position);

Comment: I have added an answer in response to your requirement. Check that out and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this for multiple tagging:

```
Class MultipleTag{
    Incident incident; // Stores incident object
    ViewHolder holder ; 

    public MultipleTag(){
         holder = new ViewHolder();
    }
    public setIncidentTag(Incident incident){
         this.incident = incident;  
    }
    public static class ViewHolder{
         TextView ... ;
         ImageView ...;
    }
}
/*  Inside the adapter's getView() method */
MutlipleTag.ViewHolder viewHolder; 
if(converView == null){
    MultipleTag obj = new MultipleTag();
    viewHolder = obj.holder; // obtain the viewHolder
    obj.setIncidentTag(incident);   // Setting incident tag.
    obj.holder.textViewitem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id...);
    // .... Initialize all the viewHolder variables

    /* now set tag to the MultipleTag object */
    convertView.setTag(position, obj);
}
else{
    MultipleTag temp = (MultipleTag)convertView.getTag(position);
    viewHolder = temp.holder; // obtain the viewHolder object.
}
```

Notice that I have declared the static ViewHolder class within the MultipleTag class and I am using just **one key(position)** to associate the tagged object instead of two(your example). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: this is pretty interesting.. lemme test it. I'll reply you next an hour

Answer (score 3):

You can use a temporary data structure and keep values based on the position. For example :

```
class YourModelClass
{
   Yourfield1;
   Yourfield2;

}
```

and keep the values in an array and then based on position in `getView` you can use it.

Tagging a value to convertView will be not useful since its going to be reused.

Comment: like HashMap<String, Object> ?

Comment: No its a custom model class used in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Use list or arraylist to store your objects and pass that list as tag.So you can access it where you want get tag there and cast to arraylist then get your objects.

Comment: I see..., the idea is to get the tagged object easily from ListView's onItemClickListener(){}

Comment: you can also retrive all objects of listview item by requesting on itemclick method public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3)   Here arg1 is listview item so you can call getchild method on it